# date(byAdding: ) is returning the incorrect value in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, swift4

I have the following code:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if let dateOpened: Date = defaults.object(forKey: "lastOpened") as? Date {

   let (intHour, intMinute, time1) = getStuffFromTime(time: alarms[i].time, amOrPm: alarms[i].amOrPm)
   // this is my own function I made, the result intHour, and intMinute (ignore time1) are of type int. intHour is always between 0 and 23, intMinute is always between 0 and 59
   let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
   var components = gregorian.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: dateOpened)
   components.hour = intHour
   components.minute = intMinute
   var myDate = gregorian.date(from: components)
   print(myDate)
   // 2017-11-04 4:13:20 PM +0000
   myDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: myDate)
   print(myDate)
   // 2017-11-05 5:13:20 PM +0000
}
```

As you can see, it did add a day to myDate, but it also added an hour to it. Does anybody know why it's doing this, or how I can avoid it from adding the extra hour? I'm just trying to add a day to the variable myDate. I've tried specifying the TimeZone of gregorian, but it has no effect.

Comment: Please post fully working code. And I cannot reproduce, might be a timezone issue.

Comment: ````let today = Date() //"Nov 4, 2017 at 1:10 PM"
let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today) //"Nov 5, 2017 at 1:11 PM"```` Used this. The method works, as everyone has suggested. If you post the full code, we can probably help debug. But it is not the case that the method is returning the wrong value.

Comment: I added my full method as everyone suggested

Comment: Are you living in a country where daylight saving time changes on November 5?

Comment: Daylight Savings Time change?

Comment: Yes, I live in the US. I guess the problem (which wasn't actually a problem) was the whole daylight savings thing. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Yes, in most of the US, we switch back to standard time tonight, so the clock will change by 1 hour.

Comment: Ha Ha. Daylight savings time changes tonight (actually at 2am tomorrow). Your computer knows this but you don't.